# Making tailwind css manual dark mode with CDN

Tags: frontend, tailwind-css

I want to make a dark/light mode with tailwind css.

I am making my backend and API in go so I would like to avoid using npm. That is why I opted for cdn based installation.

My HTML code is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html class="">

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script src="/tailwind.config.js"></script>
</head>

<body class=" bg-white dark:bg-neutral-900">
....
```

In my `tailwind.config.js` I have just this:

```
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class'
}
```

When I serve my html I have always my system preference (dark) even though in my html I have `<html class="">` and not `<html class="dark">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the CDN, as per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn), you assign your Tailwind configuration to the `tailwind.config` object, not `module.exports`:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  darkMode: 'class'
}
```

```js
tailwind.config = {
  darkMode: 'class',
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html class="">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-white dark:bg-neutral-900">
</body>
```

```js
tailwind.config = {
  darkMode: 'class',
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html class="dark">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-white dark:bg-neutral-900">
</body>
```